# PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock mode during a select query in hql for the row

Tags: locking

I am performing a select query(fetching the entire row) for multiple rows with pessimistic_write lock mode to lock the rows in the select query(HQL). Will the rows be locked until I perform an update and do a commit? I am performing a load run and encountering a update count 0 for some transactions based on my where clause last transfer id whos value I fetch in my select query which means that the last transfer id has been changed leading to the fundamental doubt on locking strategy. Can someone please throw some light upon this?